# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log{|a-e^{i\theta}|}d\theta$?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I need to calculate the integral
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log{|a-e^{i\theta}|}d\theta$$

When $|a|> 1$, I can show it equals $\log|a|$. But I failed to handle the situation when $|a|\leqslant 1$. I know it should be $0$.

I tried to use $\log(a-z)$, but when $|a|\leqslant 1$, such $\log$ can not be defined. So anyone can help?

---

Updated: the second situation should be $|a|<1$.

Comment: Why can't that function be defined when $\,|a|\le 1\,$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio, the unit circle surrounding $a$ will contain $0$, then $\log$ function has no single branch on it, right?

Comment: @DonAntonio, maybe it should be $|a|<1$

Comment: Well, two things: first, a branch cut can be chosen and we can try to work with it, and second: is your function the real or the complex logarithm? Note that you wrote in your question the absolute value of $\,a-e^{i\theta}\,$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio, when dealing with absolute value ,it is real log, otherwise it is complex log.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I thought the single branch of log can only be chosen on the complex plane excluding a ray starting at the origin.

Comment: That's what I thought, @hxhxhx88...

Comment: @julien, thanks! But I still have a confusion. In the case $|a|=1$, particularly $a=1$, is the question well-posed? Because when integrating by $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$, at some point the function $\log|a-e^{i\theta}|$ may equals $\log(0)$, which is not defined.

Comment: Was it absolutely necessary to delete my comment linking to another relevant thread? What was the motivation? Just curious.

Comment: @julien: your comment was deleted by the system. When a question is deemed a duplicate, the system removes comments that state the question is a duplicate since the question will be labelled a duplicate anyway. Unfortunately, the script doesn't realize there was more information there.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks a lot for the explanation. Strange script...

Answer (score 0):

[The Jensen's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula#Poisson.26ndash.3BJensen_formula) implies $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log{|a-e^{i\theta}|}d\theta = \max(\log(|a|),0).$$

Comment: Actually, I need to prove this formula.

Comment: [The book "Meromorphic functions"](http://www.amazon.com/Meromorphic-Functions-W-K-Hayman/dp/B000XCFU96) by W. Hayman contains its proof which does not use the integral under consideration.

Comment: The following books also deal with Jensen's Formula: Hahn , Epstein's *Classical Complex Analysis* , Stein-Shakarchi's *Complex Analysis* , Ahlfors's *Complex Analysis* , Remmert's *Classical Topics in Complex Function Theory* , etc.

Comment: @user64494, thank you for reference.